# Embedding extended XMP metadata into a PDF file

Tags: pdf, thesis, xml, metadata, xmp

I am preparing a thesis paper for submission into an electronic library database. Our institution cooperates with the British Library that uses their [EThOS](http://ethos.bl.uk/Home.do) system to harvest the papers from the local repositories of our and several other universities.

They maintain their own recommended metadata extension to the simple DC described in the [toolkit](http://ethostoolkit.cranfield.ac.uk/tiki-index.php?page_ref_id=47). A sample metadata XML file is provided [here](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/2.0/uketd.xml).

I would like to attach the metadata to my thesis. I've managed to *[extend](http://www.uschovna.cz/en/package/J14JK63EKP5ZB9AP-7NX)* the PDFX package so that it in addition to the usual PDF/A metadata also includes the additional elements defined in the sample EThOS XML file.

I am nevertheless not entirely sure this is the right way... One of the reasons is that the generated metadata file is not valid RDF. The problem is in the XSI schema required by the language tag (see the sample XML). As far as I understand RDF and XSI do not combine well. A possible workaround could be not including the XSI schema and the tags that make use of it. That's what I've been doing so far...

Given all of the above, I have two questions.

1. Is this the right way of embedding the metadata into a PDF or should I somehow attach an XML file to it? How?
2. If I am doing it right, is there a way to combine the XSI schema and RDF into a valid XMP metadata?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve no idea, but: You didn’t mention the package `hyperxmp`, was this intentionally? And the link on uschovna.cz to the extended version of `pdfx` (I assume) is expired, as it tells me.

Comment: And the manual of `hyperxmp` points to `xmpincl`. Take a closer look on both.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't re-encode the XSI as XMP, then DO NOT put it into the XMP or it will cause the file to not validate as PDF/A.

And then you will need to find a custom/private location in the PDF to put your custom data.

Comment: What about including only simple DC which does not require XSI, that should work, shouldn't it? Thanks.